# Query MACs in Wifi Access Point

Tags: telnet, openwrt

I want to be able to access the data of **MACs** that are listened from a Wi-Fi access point (TP Link) in order to register them in a **MySql** database. My first idea is to access through the **PHP** **Telnet** library to the Access Point command line to perform the queries. I understand that TP-Link works on **OpenWRT**, but I do not know how to perform the data queries:

- MAC within reach of the Access Point (even if they are not connected as clients)
- MAC connected to the Wifi Access Point.

Any guidance on how to tackle the problem?

Comment: TP link also provide a Web-Gui you can get the details from there. Telnet may not be enabled by default, but if want to use custom/root build you can start from https://wiki.openwrt.org/toh/start

Comment: TP-Link Web_gui does not allow collecting the data and sending it to a database. The only way would be to make a custom firmeware?